# Managed type/wrapper for extern keyword

Tags: c++-cli, managed-c++

I am writing a managed wrapper for a 3rd party API and I have access to only their header files and .lib file. In one of the header files there is a function:

```
extern "C" void functionName(unsigned int param);
```

To wrap this function, I can ignore the *extern* keyword right? It is just to tell the compiler to treat the declaration as if it were made in C, rather than C++ and I guess this shouldn't be an issue when writing a managed wrapper using C++/CLI?

Comment: It makes the function usable from a C program.  And from a managed program through [DllImport] so you don't have to write a C++/CLI wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `extern "C"` in a function declaration specifies C linkage for the function (i.e. no name mangling); see here:  [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-does-extern-c-in-c-source) . It should not adversely affect a C++/CLI caller.